# Difference between copy and move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

> what is difference between copy() and move_uploaded_file()

I think both the functions perform same operations then whats the difference?

```php
copy ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 
     "C:/Apache/htdocs/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] ) 


move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 
     "C:/Apache/htdocs/" . $_FILES['file']['name'])
```

Answer (score 14):

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

Answer (score 4):

Copy will copy the file source to destination whereas move will move it.

When a file is copied, a duplicate is made means temporary buffers(source) is not cleaned.

When you move a file, it is deleted from the original location means in temporary buffer (source: $_FILES) and move the file in destinations.

Comment: The OP does not ask about the difference between `copy` and `move`, but between `copy` (or `move`, although not stated) and a special function `move_uploaded_file`.

Answer (score 3):

As to complement @Muhammad Hasan Khan's answer.

According to this comment https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php#113766, **move_uploaded_file** does not bring anymore security than **is_uploaded_file**, and therefore the two followings snippets are strictly equivalent in terms of security:

```php
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if(false === is_uploaded_file($tmp)){
    return false;
}
copy($tmp, $dst);
```

```php
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $dst);
```